# How do people have mobile apps that display maps with no logo

Tags: ios, api, mobile, maps, branding

I have had a look at a bunch of different map APIs and all the ones I have found require you to display their logo

I have had a look on the IOS app store and there are loads of apps that display a map without any logo

Does anyone know how this is done?

I have noticed the Apple mapkit doesnt require a logo but that one doesnt allow you to customize the map much visually.

All that I have seen on the app store have a different design to what mapkit provides and no logo.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's MapKit allows you to customize the map visually by using the class [MKTileOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay).

Basically what you have to do is init that class with the URL of a Tile server and then add the overlay to the map view.

```
let myOverlay = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: /*Tiles server URL*/)
myOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
self.mapView.addOverlay(myOverlay)
```

Here you can check some free tiles servers:

https://openmaptiles.org

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How would I go about creating my own TileOverlay? I can see mapbox allows me to to do this but I would have to use a mapbox layer to build upon and this would mean including their logo

Comment: If you want to use MKTileOverlay you need to have a tile server that provides you the tiles for your map. I my answer you can see some free options.